# How to run `autopostgresqlbackup` in a cron job?

Tags: cron

How to run `autopostgresqlbackup` in a cron job?

I setup a new cronjob this way:

```
34 20 * * * echo "DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL" && sudo autopostgresqlbackup
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Here is the message I received in my mailbox.

```
DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL 
/bin/bash: autopostgresqlbackup: command not found
```

The [autopostgresqlbackup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/autopostgresqlbackup.8.html) is installed and working well in my server.

I want to control when backups are done through my own cron jobs, is it possible?

Comment: Please add the absolute path to `autopostgresqlbackup`

Comment: And this `echo "DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL"` will not work rather put that into a file with `>>`

Answer (score 0):

Now your cron job won't work as is:

```
34 20 * * * echo "DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL" && sudo autopostgresqlbackup
```

Several things there:

1. This `echo "DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL"` won't be seen as `cron` runs in it's own shell
2. This `sudo autopostgresqlbackup`:

   - `sudo` isn't needed to run cron job, since I assume your root
   - `autopostgresqlbackup`, the full path to this command is needed to get it to run.

So your cron job might look like this:

```
34 20 * * * echo "DAILY INTERNAL BACKUP - POSTGRESQL" >> /var/log/postlog && /path/to/binary/autopostgresqlbackup
```